# how do I get offset positions of items in my FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I would like to use FlatList method scrollToOffset to scroll to a specific item in my FlatList. The reason I am not using scrollToIndex is that with scrollToIndex I cannot control the speed of the scroll. With scrollToOffset I could use Animated library to change the value gradually. However, I have no idea how to find the offset values of items in my FlatList.

Comment: If your children are constant height, then you can calculate the offset. Alternatively you could have each child use onLayout to measure themselves and report back to the FlatList. Then you could easily calculate the offset.

Comment: Good answer here as to why RN doesn't allow this to happen https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/add-speed-attribute-to-scrollto

Answer (score -2):

have a look into flat list documentation.

```
onViewableItemsChanged
```

that might help

Comment: The offset information is not in the ViewToken returned by onViewableItemsChanged.